# Be aware that the Local Service account is not supported for the SQL Server or SQL Server Agent services

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple question. What following sentence means:
Be aware that the Local Service account is not supported for the SQL Server or SQL Server Agent services.

I have SQL Server 2008, 2008R2 and 2012 which SQL Server and SQL Server agent services runs under Local Service account.

http://sequelserver.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-service-account-privileges.html
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/31d57870-1faa-4e14-8527-ce77b1ff40e4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That generally means (used to work for MSFT many moons ago) that any problem or issue that you may call Microsoft about when the service runs under the Local Service account will not be answered or handled by their support staff.  Long story short, you're on your own when it comes to errors or other challenges.  You're best off running the services under a domain account.